# Is there any way to mention message for each image version in dockerhub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am just curious is there any way to pass message in docker push or any docker command which can be seen in docker hub like git commit -m "...".
I want to maintain  an docker image which can be used with specific versions of application code so I have to write small message for each version of container about supported code version.

Answer (score 0):

No, you could link your dockerhub repository with github, create release on github per tag and explain changes.

i.e.

Rancher server: https://hub.docker.com/r/rancher/rancher/tags & https://github.com/rancher/rancher/releases